# Проблема с закрытием вторым окном

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня проблема с закрытием вторым окном.

Тут я открываю с помощью кнопки второе окно.

```
public void Button_Open_SerialBufferWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   
    SerialBufferWindow SerialBufferWindow_variable = new SerialBufferWindow();

    SerialBufferWindow_variable.Show();

    
}
```

Но хочу закрыть это же второе окно другой кнопкой.

```
  private void Button_Clear_Serial_Buffer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox_Scan.Clear();
        Button_Clear_Scan.IsEnabled = false;
        TextBox_SerialBuffer.Clear();
        Button_Clear_Serial_Buffer.IsEnabled = false;
        Count_value = 0;
        TextBox_Boardinformation.Clear();
        Button_Open_SerialBufferWindow.IsEnabled = false;
        logger.Info(nameWin + Pass + "Serial Buffer has been cleaned");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если забыть про то, что вы работаете с WPF как с винформами, а так никто не делает, то решение будет примерно таким.

```cs
private SerialBufferWindow serialBufferWindow;

private void Button_Open_SerialBufferWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    serialBufferWindow = new SerialBufferWindow();

    serialBufferWindow.Show();
}

private void Button_Clear_Serial_Buffer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    serialBufferWindow.Close();
}
```

Осваивайте привязки данных, команды, XAML разметку и MVVM. Вот тогда мощь этой платформы вам и откроется.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за совет.
Подскажи пожалуйста как привязать данные (Текст) с тексбокса который находится в одном окне к другому текст боксу который находится в другом окне.

Comment: @i3070-inline Напрямую никак, при использовании MVVM создается строковое свойство в классе вьюмодели, и к нему можно привязать сколько угодно текстбоксов из сколько угодно окон вплоть до того, что при изменении текста в одном окне эти изменения будут в реальном времени отображаться во всех привязаных контролах. Изучите привязки данных `Binding`. Если кратко, вам нужно создать свойство, настроить `DataContext` и реализовоть для свойства `INotifyPropertyChanged`, и просто привязаться к нему в XAML.